# C# Application exit

Tags: c#

I want to know how i can do something when exiting a windows application, i wan to run a query UPDATE users SET on = 0; so i know when people are on my program

Main reason for this is i want to do a list of online people for my chat system so they know who they are chatting to i will be doing this with a foreach of where on = 1 in my mysql database users table

i have tryed doing my own close button but what do i do when it is force closed it can be force closed by task manager or if their computer restarts

Comment: Use the main window's Closing or FormClosing event.  Or put it after the Application.Run() call in your Main() method.  Do note that this is unreliable, you cannot count on your program ending normally.  A crash or the user intentionally terminating your program with Task Manager will leave your dbase out of whack.  Seeing the socket getting disconnected would be a much more reliable indication.

Comment: Usually, I do the opposite: my program sends keep-alives to the database. If this does not occur within a specified time span, the application is down/crashed.

Answer (score 4):

A program can be killed, an internet connection can go dead or a nuclear bomb could be dropped on a town.  The point is, the client can't always do the update.

Update your schema to have a "LastTimeSeen" column and have the other clients use this to decide if a peer is missing and then age that peer out of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `Form.Closing` event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx

Comment: How would a shutdown call this event?

Comment: Do i make a void for that?

Comment: @UweKeim: Windows will gracefully exit all programs.

Comment: `Caution 

The Closing event is obsolete in the .NET Framework version 2.0; use the FormClosing event instead.`

Comment: @Lintonday Yes it is void. From the form properties, select the second tab and double click the closing event.